# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar el menor por filas y guardar su posición y el número?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, números-primos

Hago el siguiente procedimiento:

1. Genero números aleatoriamento y los guardo en la matriz `mat`
2. LLeno la matriz `mpr` con ceros
3. Busco en la matriz `mat` cuáles son números primos y el número primo en la posición que se encuentre en `mat` lo llevo a la misma posición en `pmr`, quedando `mpr` con los números primos y las posiciones donde no hay primos en cero.

Necesito recorrer mi matriz `mpr` por filas y guardar en que fila se encuentra y en que `posición(i,j)` de la fila el número menor primo por cada fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*

'''
1 - Leer una matriz 4x6 entera y determinar en qué posiciones están los menores primos por fila.
'''

import random

# función que verifica si el elemento de la matriz es un número primo
def es_primo(numero):
    for i in range(2,((numero//2)+1)):
        if (numero%i)==0:
            # es divisible
            return False
    return True

# función que llena las dos matrices
def llenar_matriz_random(fil, col):
    mat = [] #Matriz que almacena todos los elementos generados al azar
    mpr = [] #Matriz que almacena los números primmos que hay en mat, inicialmente se incializa con ceros
    for i in range(fil):
        vec = []
        vpr = []
        for j in range(col):
            vec.append(random.randint(1, 50))
            vpr.append(0)
        mat.append(vec)
        mpr.append(vpr)
    return mat, mpr

# función para mostrar los elementos de las odos matrices
def mostrar_matriz(mat, mpr):
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        print (mat[i])
    for i in range(len(mpr)):
        print (mpr[i])

# función que recorre todos los elementos de mat
#verifica cual es primo y en caso de serlo lo guarda en mpr 
def extraer_primos(mat, mpr, fil, col):
    verificar = 0
    for i in range(fil):
        for j in range(col):
            verificar = mat[i][j]
            if es_primo(verificar) and verificar != 1:
                    mpr[i][j] = verificar
    return  mpr 

def main():
    fil = 4
    col = 6
    mat, mpr = llenar_matriz_random(fil, col)
    mostrar_matriz(mat, mpr)
    mpr = extraer_primos(mat, mpr, fil, col)
    print(mpr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con tu código? EN tu pregunta no es claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
# matriz es la función a evaluar
i=0
matform=[]
for i in range(matriz): # recorro las filas
    posi=-1;
    posk=-1;
    menor_primo=-1;
    sub=[]
    k=0;
    for k in range(matriz[i]): # recorro los elementos
        if(es_primo(matriz[i][k])):
            if(menor_primo==-1): # si no se habia encontrado primo, se le asigna
                menor_primo=matriz[i][k];
                posi=i; #guardo la posicion del numero primo menor en la fila 
                posk=k; #guardo la posicion del numero primo menor en la columna
            else:
                if(matriz[i][k]<menor_primo): # se evalua el elemento primo con el anterior
                    menor_primo=matriz[i][k]; #al ser menor el elemento, queda como nuevo numero primo menor
                    posi=i; #guardo la posicion del numero primo menor en la fila 
                    posk=k; #guardo la posicion del numero primo menor en la columna
    sub.append(posi);
    sub.append(posk);
    matform.append(sub); # agrego a una matriz de nfilasx2
```

Básicamente, en matform se guardan las posiciones de los números primos menores de cada fila, siguiendo el número de la fila y el número de la columna:

Por ejemplo, podría quedar así:

```
 0  1
 1  3
-1 -1
 3  0
```

Lo que significa es que le pasaste una matriz de 4 filas con n columnas y que, los números primos menores de cada fila están en:

```
 0  1 -> segundo elemento de la primera fila 
 1  3 -> cuarto elemento de la segunda fila
-1 -1 -> Esta fila no tiene números primos
 3  0 -> primer elemento de la cuarta fila
```

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero espero que te ayude!

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo te recomiendo que uses el paquete numpy. Es muy versatil e ideal para el trabajo con matrices. Tu codigo inicial quedaria algo asi. ME tome alguna atribuciones al optimizar un poco tu codigo, espero no te moleste. Fijate por ejemplo, que en la funcion es_primo, no compruebo hasta la mitad del numero, sino hasta su raiz cuadrada, que siempre es menor, puesto que si un entero tiene un multiplo mayor que su raiz cuadrada, obligatoriamente tiene otro que es menor que esta.

```
import numpy as np

def es_primo(numero):
    if numero <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(np.sqrt(numero)) + 1):
        if (numero % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def es_primo2(numero):
    if es_primo(numero):
        return numero
    else:
        return 0

def matriz_random(fil, col, minimo, maximo):
    return np.random.randint(minimo, maximo, (fil,col))

def extraer_primos(mat):
    mpr = np.zeros(mat.shape)
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        mpr[i] = list(map(es_primo2, mat[i]))
    return mpr  

def transformar_mpr(mpr):
    mpr_t = mpr.copy()
    for i in range(mpr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mpr.shape[1]):
            if mpr[i][j] == 0:
                mpr_t[i][j] = np.Infinity
    return mpr_t

def obtener_posicion(numero, matriz):
    i, j = 0, 0
    for i in range(matriz.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matriz.shape[1]):
            if matriz[i][j] == numero:
                return i, j

def main():
    fil = 4
    col = 6
    mat = matriz_random(fil, col, 1, 50)
    mpr = extraer_primos(mat)
    print(mat)
    print(mpr)

    mpr2 = transformar_mpr(mpr)
    print(mpr2)
    minimo = mpr2.min()

    print("El menor primo de la matriz es {}".format(int(minimo)))

    i_min, j_min = obtener_posicion(minimo, mat)
    print("Y se encuentra en la siguiente posicion:")
    print("i_min = {}".format(i_min))
    print("j_min = {}".format(j_min))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de problemas son idóneos para tratarlos desde el punto de vista de la *programación funcional*.

Por ejemplo, para obtener la matriz `mpr` se usaría una compresión de listas:

```py
def filtra_primo(n):
    return n if es_primo(n) else 0

mpr = [[filtra_primo(x) for x in row] for row in mat]
```

Para obtener el mínimo primo por fila y posición, transformamos la matriz en tuplas de `(posición, valor)` y filtramos los items de valor cero:

```py
mpr_prima = [[t for t in enumerate(row) if t[1] != 0] for row in mpr]
```

Y calculamos los mínimos de cada fila usando la función `min()` y el `operator.itemgetter`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

primos_minimos = [min(row, key=itemgetter(1)) for row in mpr_prima]
```

La lista `primos_minimos` es una lista de tuplas `(posición, primo)`, una tupla por fila.